# Return false if no rows for select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next query:

```
SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN test_date < now() THEN true
    ELSE false
END AS "isTest"
FROM user_test_date
WHERE new_date is NULL AND login_id = 1
```

It works fine, if we have some records in `new_date` table, but if it is empty for some user, query just returns empty string. How I can return `false`, if there are no records also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just selects an `EXISTS` expression here:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_test_date
               WHERE test_date < NOW() AND new_date IS NULL AND login_id = 1) AS isTest;
```

This would always return just a single record, containing a boolean value of true or false.

Answer (score 3):

@Tim Biegeleisen
`EXISTS` can only be used in a `WHERE` clause or somewhere the result can be used in a query or subquery. Try the simple `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1)` to test it out. You will get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'.`

@Ted
If you are looking for a true/false result even when there is not a record to compare your datetime with, then you would need something like this.

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN ( --check if record exists
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM user_test_date
            WHERE new_date IS NULL AND login_id = 1
            ) < 1 THEN 'false'
    ELSE ( --otherwise, check test_date
            SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN test_date < GetDate() Then 'true' 
                ELSE 'false' 
            END
            FROM user_test_date
            where new_date IS NULL AND login_id = 1
            )
END AS "isTest"
```